# RecyclerView not showing all item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

here is my recycler view adapter snippet.

```
 @Override
    protected void
    onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParentStatsViewHolder holder,
                     int position, @NonNull ChildModal model) {

        /*TODO: CURRENTLY SHOW SINGLE ITEM, FIX TO SHOW ALL*/

        mapFromFirebase = model.getAppsList();

        List<String> keyset = new ArrayList<>(mapFromFirebase.keySet());

        List<Long> values = new ArrayList<>(mapFromFirebase.values());

        Log.d("ParentStatsAdapter", keyset.toString());

        String pkgnamE = keyset.get(position);

        holder.pkgName.setText(pkgnamE);
        holder.usageTime.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(values.get(position) / 1000));
        Log.d("Positionofsdsd", String.valueOf(position));
    }
```

As you see, when i log "ParentStatsAdapter", it return a whole keyset, which more than 1. The keyset return [Telegram, Blocked Numbers Storage, Package installer, Messenger,].
But when i log "Positionofsdsd", it only return [Telegram]. I already set layout_height="wrap content" for my itemview.

Comment: Please add your layout of item and fragment/activity

Comment: can you please share full code of adapter? I think you have not implemented adapter properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you override "getItemCount()"?
I will assume that this function at you is not redefined. Add a function that returns the size of your array.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mapFromFirebase.size();
}
```